# How to setup CloudFlare Origin CA with a wordpress server hosted on Amazon AWS?

Tags: wordpress, security-certificate, webserver, cloudflare, amazon-aws

Many might know that recently CloudFlare introduced something really amazing for everyone with a domain: [CloudFlare Origin CA](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-ca-encryption-origin/).

I have a WordPress website hosted on Amazon AWS, and what I initially wanted to do is run my whole website on HTTPS only.

I was able to configure Universal SSL from CloudFlare, and what I want to do now is have the origin server encrypted by SSL.

CloudFlare Origin CA is meant to do this, but I am unable to work out how.

There are currently no tutorials on using CloudFlare Origin CA, so I am having trouble figuring out what to do.

Answer (score 2):

The AWS [Certificate Manager](https://aws.amazon.com/certificate-manager/) product does not support third party certificates so you will need to import the CloudFlare certificate from within the AWS [Identity and Access Management](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/) product, where you can upload the 3 files required - the server certificate and private key in PEM format, and the certificate chain file.

Further reading:

- [AWS IAM User Guide - Managing Your Server Certificates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_server-certs_manage.html),
- [CloudFlare Blog: Introducing CloudFlare Origin CA](https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-ca-encryption-origin/)

Answer (score 0):

So after much clarifications, now anyone can easily use those Origin CA Certificates.

Suppose you are having a LEMP server and possibly using a letsencrypt certificate.

You will first need to issue the Cloudflare Origin CA Certs from Cloudflare's website.

Post that install it on your server and the needful configuration.
For me, it was setting up Ngnix properly after uploading the certs.

After that, you will have to enable Cloudflare proxy on your website to make the certificate work.

I've configured it and confirmed that you can only use those Origin CA certs with Cloudflare enable on your websites.